# Replacing a value in a arraylist that is type data structure

Tags: java, arraylist

This is probably a very simple question, but I will still ask it.

My arraylist:

```
ArrayList<FileNameData> fileData;
```

FileNameData class:

```
public FileNameData(TCComponentItemRevision rev, TCComponentDataset selectedDataset, String markUp, String fileName)
```

set Method

```
public void setFileName(String fName) {
   fileName = fName;
}
```

I am trying to take the users input for file name and replace the file name already in the array.

I created the following method.

```
public void setFileName(int index, String fName) {
    fileData.set(index, setFileName(fName));
}
```

I know to get the file name it is very simple

```
String fName = fileData.get(index).getFileName();
```

I know that the set method needs the index and new value, but I am not sure how to get to the setFileName method inside the set?

Comment: Get a new name for an already existing file and update it?

Answer (score 2):

If I get you right, then you want to modify the object that is stored at position `index`:

```
public void setFileName(int index, String fName) {
    fileData.get(index).setFileName(fName);
}
```

Or, with some more lines:

```
public void setFileName(int index, String fName) {
    // get the fileNameData stored at position index
    FileNameData fileNameData = fileData.get(index);

    // set the new filename
    fileNameData.setFileName(fName);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get the file a particular file from the ArrayList and change the name of the file, you need to get the correct element from the list.

If you know the index of the old file, it is fairly simple:

```
file = list.get(index);
file.setName(newName);
```

You can use the [`indexOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#indexOf%28java.lang.Object%29) method of [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html). for this the [`equals`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) and [`hashcode`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) of the `FileData` object must be implemented correctly. Assuming that the name of the file uniquely identifies a file:

In the FileData class

```
public boolean equals(Object other)
{
    return other instanceof FileData 
           && this.getFileName().equals(((FileData)other)getName());
}

public int hashCode()
{
    return this.getFileName().hashCode();
}
```

Then you can find the index of the file with a given name and update it:

```
FileData file = new FileData();
file.setName(oldName);
int index = list.indexOf(file);
file = list.get(index);
file.setName(newName);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you have two classes looking something like this:

```
class SomeClass {
    ArrayList<FileNameData> fileData;

    public SomeClass(){
        fileData = new ArrayList<FileNameData>();   
    }
}
```

and

```
class FileNameData {

    String fileName;

    public FileNameData(TCComponentItemRevision rev, TCComponentDataset selectedDataset, String markUp, String fileName){ ... }

    public void setFileName(String fName) { 
        fileName = fName; 
    }

    public String getFileName() { 
        return fileName;
    }
}
```

So, you'll need to find a way to get the index where the current fileName is storred.

Once you have the index, you can just do the following (should be done in `SomeClass`, so that class will look like:

```
class SomeClass {
    ArrayList<FileNameData> fileData;

    public SomeClass(){
        fileData = new ArrayList<FileNameData>();   
    }

    public void replaceFileNameAtIndex(int index, String fileName){
           fileData.get(index).setFileName(fileName);
    }
}
```

One way of finding the index could be:

```
public int findIndexOfFilleName(String fileName){
     for (FileNameData file : fileData)
        if (file.getFileName().equals(fileName))
            return fileData.indexOf(file);
    return -1; //or some other value indicating not found
}
```

Comment: Your loop to find the index is redundant. All you need is `return fileData.indexOf(file);`

Comment: @Nivas That's true, but I think it reads better this way (at least easier to understand when you start learning to use collections).

Comment: I dont think so. You are looping on the list and still calling `indexOf`. This means `indexOf` gets called 10 times for a list 10 long. Why loop at all? Just call `indexOf`. Once.

Comment: Actually that is not true. `indexOf()` is just called once, if the file names equals each other.

Comment: Agreed. but when `indexOf` is called, the file names are already equal. So you dont need the `indexOf` call at all. `file.getFileName().equals(fileName)` and `fileData.indexOf(file);` are equivalent statements. You dont need both. Also, if you see the [sourcecode](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/ArrayList.java.html) of `ArrayList.indexOf`, there is actually loop in it. So with your code, you end up looping on the `ArrayList` twice which is not needed at all.